# Combining DEM file with building (height) vector files using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, dem, merge

I am using ArcMap 10.2. I need a DSM file to use for my thesis to run visibility analysis on it, but my case study (Tehran) do not have LiDAR data.

So I am thinking to combine a DEM file with building vector files which includes height.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Could this post help you? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/150832/46073

Comment: Your building heights have elevations representing distance above ground?  If so, convert the buildings to a raster layer and add the buildings layer to the DEM file.  If your building heights are elevation values then you could convert the buildings to raster and use a CON function to replace the DEM pixels with the building pixels.  Of course, this assumes the buildings and the DEM share the same vertical datum.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have both raster and vector in the same Coordinate Reference System (CRS).

In ArcGIS 10.2, first use [Feature to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000002v000000) to convert the building vector to raster. In the `field` parameter, choose the 'height' column. Try setting the cell size equal to DEM's cell size.

Then, use the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) to add values from the 'height raster' to DEM. Something like:

```
"height_raster" + "DEM"
```

Alternatively, one can also use [Cell Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/) to sum values from both rasters.

A Spatial Analyst license is required with both `Raster Calculator` and `Cell Statistics`.