# Convert an OSM to a Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap

I am trying to convert an .osm file to a .shp file.

I am using OGR2OGR.
There is an [article at Openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OGR) which explains how this can be done. Here is an example command:

```
ogr2ogr.exe --config OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING NO -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.osm
```

And it works perfectly. As a result of upper command, in the "output.shp" folder I get four separate .shp files:
*lines.shp*, *multilinestrings.shp*, *multipolygons.shp*, *points.shp*

However what I would like to get is a single .shp file. So basically to convert an .osm file to a single .shp file.

Is it possible to do that directly through some change of the upper command?

If not then I tried to merge all these four .shp file into a single .shp file (*merged.shp*). I found an example topic [here at gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25004/open-source-software-to-merge-large-shape-files). So I used the following 4 commands:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" merged.shp lines.shp
ogr2ogr.exe -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" -update -append merged.shp multilinestrings.shp
ogr2ogr.exe -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" -update -append merged.shp multipolygons.shp
ogr2ogr.exe -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" -update -append merged.shp points.shp
```

And the merged.shp file is created, but an error is raised at the upper last (fourth) command:

```
Attempt to write non-linestring (POINT) geometry to ARC type shapefile.
```

I tried to google but I couldn't solve this error.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: From what I understand, you're trying to combine points, lines and polygons into one shapefile...  That's impossible.  Shapefiles only hold a single geometry type per file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Fezter!
If I can't combine different geometry type, then is there a way I could force all four shape files to have the same ```keys```?
For example the lines.shp may have the ```highway``` key, while multipolygons.shp may not have. Can I still force both of them to contain this key? The ```highway``` is just an example. Basically I would like to have all four shape files (created from an .osm file) to have the same number of keys, even though they may not useful to some of them.

Comment: Do you mean attributes? Yes, you can certainly do that, but I suggest asking a new question. And include the software you have available.

Comment: I am using OGR2OGR.exe from GDAL project. That's the only software. In open street map they are called: keys. For example, a key ```building``` has a value of ```yes```.
But I assume those are attributes. I apologize for my ignorance.
I will post a new question.
Thank you.

Comment: @Fezter, can you post your reply as an answer, instead of a comment?
So that I can mark it as the correct answer.
Thank you.

Comment: No, the question has been closed as a duplicate and cannot accept answers.

Comment: You may change to some other format that allows mixed geometries.

Comment: @AndreJ thank you for the reply! That other format is not a .shp file, but which one?

Comment: Geojson would be my best bet. gml and kml will work too, and spatialite stores all geometry types in different tables within the same file. Ogr2ogr can export to all of them.

Comment: Thank you @AndreJ. As always your replies have been of much help to me.